# Ionic react splash screen is showing two times with capacitor

Tags: android, ionic-framework, splash-screen, capacitor

I am a building android app using ionic react + capacitor

I added the splash screens with their correct sizes
but on app loading splash screens are displayed two times.

Find below image, app splash screen displayed two times:

I tried my ways to correct it but not able to find cause.

Can someone please help me.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem.

Problem is that, I used transparent image for splash screens, which causing above problem of duplicate splash screen display.

By replacing all the splash screens with white background solved the problem.